# Erro em instalação de Pacote?

Tags: r

Estou tentando instalar esse seguinte pacote de geração de mapas mas esta dando o seguinte erro

***install.packages("maptools",dep=TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/rafael/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Aviso: unable to access index for repository http://cran-r.c3sl.ufpr.br/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Aviso: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Mensagens de aviso perdidas:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") :
  não foi possível conectar a 'cran.r-project.org' na porta 80.
2: package ‘maptools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)***

Alguém sabe me dizer como resolver ?

Comment: Dê mais informações sobre sua sessão (versão do R, Sistema Operacional etc.). De todo jeito, eu tentaria outro repositório e checaria a internet.

Comment: Como você pode verificar aqui (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/index.html) o maptools está disponível para qualquer versão do R superior ao R 2.10. Acredito que possa ser um problema na sua conexão ou naquele repositório em especial.

Comment: Rafael, este é um computador de trabalho? Está parecendo que o acesso aos espelhos do CRAN foram bloqueados.

Comment: Sim e o computador do meu estagio ! já tentei com o login de ADM mas não da certo !

Comment: Estou no Windows 7 Versão do R 3.0.3 64 bits

Comment: Também não consigo atualizar pacotes já existentes

Comment: Rafael, é um problema da rede que você está utilizando, você terá que ver isso com a área de TI do seu estágio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael, caso você esteja utilizando o **RStudio** basta especificar o caminho ali onde coloquei a seta vermelha e depois instalar digitando o nome do pacote ali em Packages.

Caso especifique pelo menu poderás instalar via `install.packages("maptools")`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou tentar novamente utilizando o ADM aqui do meu estagio !

Comment: Só deu certo no R Studio mas estou com incompatibilidade de versões, vou atualiza-la e ver no que da !